# how to get accurate Decimal points in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, model-view-controller

This is my query and i want to get only up to 2 decimal points

```
select (select ISNULL(sum(CONVERT(decimal(6,2),w1.Party_Weight))/CONVERT(decimal(6,2),1000),0) from weight1 as w1)+
(select ISNULL(sum(CONVERT(decimal(6,2),w2.Party_Weight))/CONVERT(decimal(6,2),1000),0) from weight2 as w2)+
(select ISNULL(sum(CONVERT(decimal(6,2),w3.Party_Weight))/CONVERT(decimal(6,2),1000),0) from weight3 as w3) as Party_Weight
```

this query result is 4.493000 but I want 4.49 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert *after doing the arithmetic*!

```
select convert(decimal(6, 2), sum(w1.Party_Weight) / 1000.0) 
from weight1 aw1
```

Comment: let me check it Gordon Linoff

Comment: it returning 2 0's after decimal not the value.